# APIを用いてjson形式にしたRSSをd3.jsに読み込みforceモデルを出力したい

Tags: javascript, html

現在こちらのサイト様( http://qiita.com/tag1216/items/b7f846af66db30b8c393 ),( http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045 )を参考にしながらjson形式で読み込んだRSSをforceモデルで表示させようとしておりますが、上手くいかない状況です。

```js
var url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/hatena/b/hotentry&num=-1";
var proxy_url = "http://allow-any-origin.appspot.com/" + encodeURIComponent(url);


var WIDTH = 800,
  HEIGHT = 800,
  TAG_IMAGE = 16,
  ITEM_IMAGE_SIZE = 8,
  APPEND_INTERVAL = 250;


var tags = [];
var items = [];
var nodes = [];
var links = [];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", WIDTH)
  .attr("height", HEIGHT);

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([WIDTH, HEIGHT])
  .nodes(nodes)
  .links(links)
  .charge(0)
  .linkDistance(20)
  .linkStrength(1)
  .gravity(0.3)
  .start();

var itemNode = svg.selectAll(".item-node");
var tagNode = svg.selectAll(".tag-node");
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")

force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });
  itemNode.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
  tagNode.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
});


/*//データ読み込み*/
d3.json(proxy_url, function(error, json) {
  if (error) {
    return console.warn(error);
  }

　　　/*コンソールにタイトル、リンク、カテゴリを表示*/
  var feeds = json.responseData.feed;

  for (var i = 0; i < feeds.entries.length; i++) {
    title = feeds.entries[i].title;
    link = feeds.entries[i].link;
    tags = feeds.entries[i].categories;
    console.log(title);
    console.log(link);
    console.log(tags);
  };


  var index = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    try {
      if (json.length <= index) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        showMessage("");
        return;
      }
      showMessage("データ追加中(" + (index + 1) + "/" + json.length + ")...");
      appendItem(json[index++])
    } catch (e) {
      showMessage(e);
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, APPEND_INTERVAL);


});

/*//メッセージ*/
function showMessage(text) {
  d3.select(".message").text(text);
}




/*//投稿をノードとして追加*/
function appendItem(item) {
  items.push(item);
  nodes.push(item);
  item.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
    var name = "___" + tag.name;
    if (!(name in tags)) {
      tags[name] = tag;
      tags[name].count = 0;
      nodes.push(tags[name]);
    }
    tags[name].count++;
    links.push({
      source: nodes.indexOf(item),
      target: nodes.indexOf(tags[name])
    });
  });
  restart();
}


/*forceレイアウトの再描画*/

function restart() {
  itemNode = itemNode.data(json);
  tagNode = tagNode.data(d3.values(tags));

  drawItemNode();
  drawTagNode();
  drawLink();

  force
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .charge(function(d) {
      //反発力を 投稿数の多いタグ > 投稿数の少ないタグ > 投稿ノード にする
      return d.count ? -(d.count * 200) : -100;
    });

  force.start();
}


/* 投稿ノードの描画*/
function drawItemNode() {
  var g = itemNode.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node item")
    .call(force.drag);
  var a = g.append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
      return d.link;
    })
    .attr("target", "_blank");
  a.append("circle")
    .attr("r", ITEM_IMAGE_SIZE);
  a.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
      var imgCheck = entry.content.match(/<img.+?src="\/\/(.+?\/images\?q=.+?)\"/);
      if (igCheck) {
        var eimg = "http://" + imgCheck;

      } else {
        eimg = "http://design-ec.com/d/e_others_50/l_e_others_500.png";
      }
      return eimg
    })

  .attr({
    x: -ITEM_IMAGE_SIZE / 2,
    y: -ITEM_IMAGE_SIZE / 2,
    width: ITEM_IMAGE_SIZE,
    height: ITEM_IMAGE_SIZE
  });
  g.append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.title;
    });
}



/*タグノードの描画*/
function drawTagNode() {
  var g = tagNode.enter().insert("g", ".item")
    .attr("class", "node tag")
    .call(force.drag);
  var a = g.append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
      return "b.hatena.ne.jp/hotentry/" + d.categories;
    })
    .attr("target", "_blank");
  a.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
      return d.icon_url == "/icons/medium/missing.png" ? "http://qiita.com/icons/medium/missing.png" : d.icon_url;
    });
  a.append("rect");
  a.append("text")
    .attr("class", "shadow");
  a.append("text")
    .attr("class", "text");

  tagNode.selectAll("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });



  tagNode.each(function(d) {
    var size = ~~(TAG_IMAGE_SIZE * Math.sqrt(d.count));
    d3.select(this).select("image")
      .attr({
        x: -size / 2,
        y: -size / 2,
        width: size,
        height: size
      });
    d3.select(this).select("rect")
      .attr({
        x: -size / 2,
        y: -size / 2,
        width: size,
        height: size
      });
    d3.select(this).selectAll("text")
      .attr("dy", size / 2 + 10);
  });


  /*    リンクの描写*/
  function drawLink() {
    link = link.data(links);
    link.enter().insert("line", ".tag")
      .attr("class", "link");
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>はてなブックマーク新着記事を表示</title>
<style>
  svg {
    border: solid 1px;
  }
  .item image {
    opacity: .7;
  }
  .item circle {
    fill: #fff;
    fill-opacity: .7;
    stroke-width: .5px;
    stroke: #60c90d;
    stroke-opacity: .7;
  }
  .tag image {
    opacity: .9;
  }
  .tag rect {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    stroke: #0f6faf;
    stroke-opacity: .9;
  }
  .tag text {
    pointer-events: none;
    font-size: 8px;
  }
  .tag .shadow {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 3px;
    stroke-opacity: .7;
  }
  .link {
    stroke: #aaa;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    opacity: .3;
  }
</style>

<html>
<!--  <head>

  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/hatena/b/hotentry&num=-1";
  var proxy_url = "http://allow-any-origin.appspot.com/" + encodeURIComponent(url);


d3.json(proxy_url, function(error, json) {
    if (error) {
      return console.warn(error);
    }


     var feeds = json.responseData.feed;

       for(var i =0;i < feeds.entries.length;i++){
    title = feeds.entries[i].title;
    link = feeds.entries[i].link;
    tags = feeds.entries[i].categories;
    console.log(title);
    console.log(link);
    console.log(tags);
    };

  });
  </script> -->
</head>

<body>
  <script　src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="message"></div>
    <script src="hatena.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

上記のスニペットに書いているjsファイルを"hatena.js"として保存し、ｈｔｍｌを実行した場合
TypeError: Cannot read property 'tags' of undefined
というエラーが表示されます。
参照しているRSS( http://feeds.feedburner.com/hatena/b/hotentry/ )上にはtagという情報がないため代替としてsubjectというもので代用しようと思ったのですが指定の仕方がわかりませんでした。
イメージとしては記事のサムネイルが上記サイト様の投稿ノードの部分に入り、タグノードにカテゴリーを表示させるプログラムが作りたいと考えています。
コンソールには記事のタイトル、リンク、カテゴリーが表示されるため正しくRSSは読み込めていると思います。
スニペット上でhtmlからjsファイルを開く方法が分からなく、不恰好な形での質問になってしまい申し訳ありません。
お力添えの方よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

まだ仕様が決っていない感じですね。
何が出来るのか分からない段階では仕方無いかもしれません。

http://b.hatena.ne.jp/hotentry の利用も検討されているようですね。
これはHTMLのページですから、いわゆる「スクレイピング」をする事になります。
こういった事はサーバサイドでやる事が多いですが、今は`DOMParser`もあるので、ブラウザ側でやるのも簡単です。
ただ、APIやRSSなどより仕様(というかHTMLタグの構造)の変更が頻繁でしょうから、そこは面倒かもしれません。

下記スニペットはスクレイピングの例です。
ライブラリを使用していないので定型的な処理がいろいろありますが、そんなに多くの事はしていません。
結果はとりあえず、「名前の配列の配列」にしています。
記事タイトルもタグも、「名前」としてフラットに並べています。
まずは出来るだけ単純な構造にして、それを表示する、という所から出発するのがよいと思います。
(質問者さんが使っている、http://allow-any-origin.appspot.com/ を使用していますが、開発中や本番で使用してよい物かは知りません)

```js
"use strict";
function for_each(array, func){ Array.prototype.forEach.call(array, func); }

function get_html(callback){
 var hatena_hotentry_url = "http://b.hatena.ne.jp/hotentry";
 hatena_hotentry_url = "http://allow-any-origin.appspot.com/"
  + encodeURIComponent(hatena_hotentry_url);
 
 // var hatena_hotentry_url = "./hatena_hotentry.html"

 var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
 req.open("GET", hatena_hotentry_url);
 req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200) {
   callback(req.responseText);
   req = undefined;
  }
 };
 req.send(null);
}

function html_to_relation(html){
 var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
 var error_tags = doc.getElementsByTagName("parsererror");
 if(error_tags.length){
  console.log("error: ", error_tags);
  return [["Parse error", "Maybe HTML is broken"]];
 }

 var relation = []; // [["name", ...], ...]
 var entry_elms = doc.querySelectorAll(
   "[data-track-section='default'] .entry-contents");
 for_each(entry_elms, function(entry_elm){
  var entry_link_elm = entry_elm.querySelector(".entry-link");
  if(!entry_link_elm){ return; }

  var name_array = [];
  relation.push(name_array);
  name_array.push(entry_link_elm.title);

  var entry_meta_elm = entry_elm.nextElementSibling;
  if(!entry_meta_elm){ return; }
  for_each(entry_meta_elm.querySelectorAll("a.tag"), function(tag_elm){
   name_array.push(tag_elm.textContent);
  });
 });

 return relation;
}

function relation_view(relation){
 document.getElementById("view").textContent
         = JSON.stringify(relation, undefined, 2);
}

get_html(function(html){ relation_view(html_to_relation(html)); });
```

```html
<div>
 <pre id="view">表示エリア</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: mjy様
何から何まで本当にありがとうございます...
こちらのプログラムをいったん一通り考えて配列を見てみたりしてみました。
for文を用いてタグだけを参照することができたので、それをd3,jsのタグノードのところに入れることができればタグは表示できるのではないかなと思いました。
forceモデルを作る過程で今までjsonファイルを読み込むか、入れ子構造で最初から定義しておいた配列の要素にアクセスするという方法しか行ったことがないのですが、このプログラムはfunction relation_viewのところでjsonファイルに整形されているのでしょうか？
あくまでrelation配列は単純な配列という解釈で間違っていないでしょうか？

Comment: そうです配列（の配列）です。JSON.stringifyは見やすく表示する為だけに使っています。これを使う場合、まずはこの配列からforceモデルの‘.nodes‘に与えるノード配列を作成するのを目標にされるとよいと思います。とりあえずノードがあれば`.links`に与えるリンク配列は空でも表示のテストが出来ます。繋がりが無いので、円形にひろがるはずです。

Comment: mjy様
書いて頂いたスニペットのソースの一番後ろにrelation配列をnodes配列に入れるためのコードを追加してみようとしたのですが、relation is not defined　が出てしまいます。どこかのfunctionの中からでないとアクセスできないのでしょうか？
それとも私の配列の指定が間違っているのでしょうか?
理解力が乏しく申し訳ありません...

Comment: relationというのはrelation_view関数の引数名です。グローバル変数ではありません。おっしゃる通り、relation_view関数の中からしかアクセス出来ません。

Comment: mjy様
nodes配列を作り、そこに入れ込みたいのですがグローバル変数に宣言し直すことは可能なのでしょうか？
もしくはrelation_viewの中でd3.jsのノードなどを展開するべきなのでしょうか？

Comment: relation_viewの中で行なうべきです。もしくは、relation_viewから呼び出す関数に引数で渡しても構いません。あらかじめ宣言されたグーバル変数に代入する事は出来ますが、コールバック主体のプログラミングスタイルでグローバル変数をハンドリングするのは大変難しいです。

Comment: mjy様　なるほど、ありがとうございます。いろいろ試してみたのですがまたうまく動かなくなったので改めて質問を立てたいと思います。。。

Answer (score 0):

回答というよりは、感想のような物になります。

#### "tags"について

'tags'に関連したエラーが出ているという事ですが、行番号は大事です。
エラーが出た行から辿っていくといろいろ分かる事が多いです。

Qiitaの`tags`の代りに、RSSの`dc:subject`を使うとの事ですが、これはGoogleのAPIでjsonに変換された時点で、`feeds.entries[i].categories`になっていますし、質問者さんもこれをログに出す事には成功しているようですね。このやり方でよさそうです。
例えば、`appendItem`関数では、`item.tags`を使っていますが、これを`item.categories`にしていく感じでしょうか。

ところで参考になさっているコードでは、

> 同時に使用されていたタグ同士をリンクとして表している

との事ですが、はてなのRSSのdc:subject (jsonになった時の`feeds.entries[i].categories`) の要素は一つです。
はてなブックマークのエントリーは、ただ一つのカテゴリに所属するようです。
これは解決可能なのでしょうか。

#### コードをざっと見て気になった点

- ささいな事

  - GoogleのAPIは[JSONPをサポートしています](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide#using_callback)
    オリジンの問題を回避する為に”http://allow-any-origin.appspot.com/"を使う必要は無いです。まあJSONPは面倒ではありますよね。
  - 63行目あたりに、全角スペースがある
    JavaScriptでは許されているので、何も問題ないのですが、コピペなどで他に移した時にトラブルの元になります。よいエディタを使って、インデントなどは自動でやってもらうのがよいです。
- 参考コードと大分違う

  - linkの宣言箇所でコードがごっそり抜けている
    `var link = svg.selectAll('.link')`で終了していますが、参考コードではメソッドチェーンが続いています。
  - 上記あたりから辿っていくと、足りない物がいろいろ見つかりそう
    ここらへんで、はてなブックマークののカテゴリが一つな事が気になったので、これ以上見ていないです。

#### アルゴリズムでなく、入力データの構造を変更するという手もある

Qiitaのデータを処理するプログラムを変更して、はてなのデータを読ませようとしている分けですが、一番早いのは、はてなのデータをQiita互換の構造に変換してしまう事だと思います。
将来、はてな以外のデータを読ませる場合にも対応しやすい考え方です。
もちろん、参考コードはあくまで叩き台である、というような場合はこれでは駄目ですし、目的次第ではありますが。

Comment: mjy様
たびたび貴重なご意見ありがとうございます。非常に勉強になります。
linkの宣言の件ですが、１つ目のリンクのソースで一番最後にメソッドチェーンが書かれており、そちらを参考に致しました。
カテゴリーについてはこの質問を書いてから私の方でも気になりどうしようか考えていたところです。
タグをそもそも表示させず、投稿だけをサムネイルでフォースモデルで表示するか、カテゴリーのforceモデルを準備し、そちらをクリックするとそのカテゴリーの新着記事をフォースモデルで表示するかどちからにしょうと思います。
いずれにせよ記事をサムネイルで表示させることができなければ実現が難しいため同じ壁にぶつかっていることに変わりはありません...
入力データの構造を変更するというお話が非常になるほどと感じたのですが、例えばソースは参考にさせて頂いているものを利用するとして、読み込んだRSSのjsonを同じ形式に変更するにはどのような方法がありますでしょうか？
プログラムで変更し、そのあともう一度jsonとして書き出すような形でしょうか？
知識、技術とも未熟なため質問ばかりで申し訳ありません...。

Comment: 追記：はてなブックマークのトップページ(http://b.hatena.ne.jp/hotentry )を確認したところカテゴリーの他にタグが設定されていました。こちらをどうにか取得することが出来ればよいのですが、ＲＳＳだけでは少々難しそうです...